# Blade template does not want to load from Laravel Package

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I am loading the view in the package with

`$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'../../resources/views', 'admin');`

But when I request the page I get an error

InvalidArgumentException
View [test] not found.

Interesting twist, when I put the complete path to the view folder in the loadViewsFrom method the template loads.

I load the blade template with the following code

```
public function showTest()
{
    return view('admin::test');
}
```

Right above the loadViewsFrom method, I call loadRoutesFrom method

`$this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'../../routes/admin.php');`

And this loads without any issue.

Any suggestions what could be the issue? The code of the package is very plain, load a blade template when a route is called.

Comment: Could you add the code where you are trying to return the view.

Comment: @Remul done, added the code snippet, it is located in a controller

Comment: And  `__DIR__.'../../resources/views'` actually points to the correct directory?

Comment: In [telescope](https://github.com/laravel/telescope)  for example it is `__DIR__.'/../resources/views'` as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/blob/3.x/src/TelescopeServiceProvider.php#L35), but i don't know how you structured your package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by fixing the paths to view folder.

After verifying the exact location of my file by

```
dd(__DIR__);
```

I worked my way back to the correct path of the view folder, which was just one folder lower and not to.